# how to convert HTML form into a clickable link?

Tags: html

I have a form with a button which submit a form and open the page in a new window, my requirement is to get rid of this button in the page and add that into a menu navigation which make up of "`<a><ul><li>`" tags,

so i am wondering how do i send these same data with a HTML link (must be send as a post as its a form submitted with the post method) following is the form coding

```
<form action="{url_main_only}:9090/login.jsp" name="loginForm" method="post" target="_blank">

<input type="hidden" name="url" value="/index.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="username" size="15" maxlength="50" id="u01" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="password" size="15" maxlength="50" id="p01" value="{id}">
<input type="submit" value="&nbsp; Login Openfire Administrative">

</form>
```

AND may main menu HTML CODE is generated as follows

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="{url}">
<img src="{url_tmpl_admin}img/user.png"> Login to Openfire </a>  
</li>
.....
</ul>
```

any easy way of doing this ?

Comment: you want to send form fields value on click of `<a>` link ? is it call form action url or link url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the form an id:

```
<form id="loginform" method="POST" action="...">
...
</form>
```

Then in your button, invoke the POST:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('loginform').submit();">Login to Openfire</a>
```